# Pandas check for substring of x in column if found add string to x

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

My dataframe has a max of 2 variations of each string e.g if the string is 'USD' then sometimes another entry with 'LDUSD' is present also...the entries without 'LD' are always present.

I need to apply x[0:2]+'_'+x[2:] but ONLY if the column contains an exact match of x[2:].

It must be done this way to ensure the change only happens to the relevant entries, as there are also various items which include either 'LD' in their default name e.g ('EGLD','LDO','SLD') or include the current x string e.g.('TUSD','USDT').

```
df['Asset'] = df['Asset'].apply(lambda x: x[0:2]+'_'+x[2:] if x[2:] in df['Asset'] else x)
```

The part after...in...doesn't work, and I'm at a loss as to how to proceed next.
How do I check if the column ['Asset'] holds an exact match of x[2:]?

Apologies for the title I didn't really know what to call this one...

EDIT a few examples out of circa 400:

```
df['Asset'] = ['1INCH','AAVE','ADA','ALGO','EGLD','DASH','LDO','TUSD','USDT','LD1INCH','LDALGO','LDEGLD','LDDASH','LDLDO','LDTUSD','LDUSDT',]
```

What I need:

```
df['Asset'] = ['1INCH','AAVE','ADA','ALGO','EGLD','DASH','LDO','TUSD','USDT','LD_1INCH','LD_ALGO','LD_EGLD','LD_DASH','LD_LDO','LD_TUSD','LD_USDT',]
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to copy-paste a few sample lines from `df`? Not totally understanding the verbal description.

Comment: I think you might have just messed up x[2:-1]

Comment: You are correct I edited it to x[2:]

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren That's only part of it. `in` doesn't work for columns like this. Need something like `str.contains()` as in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`str.contains()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to test if `any()` match `rf'^{x[2:]}$'`:

```py
df['Asset'] = df['Asset'].apply(lambda x: x[:2]+'_'+x[2:]
    if df['Asset'].str.contains(rf'^{x[2:]}$', regex=True).any() else x)
```

---

For regex, add `r` to make it a raw string. In this case we also add the `f` so we can interpolate `x[2:]` via [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-denote-f-strings):

- `^` - beginning of string
- `{x[2:]}` - interpolate `x[2:]` inside the f-string
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Why is fstring not breaking for strings with size less than 3? It's not because I tried it, but I don't understand.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren `s='A'; s[2:]` evals to `''`

Comment: I did not know that about strings, today I learned. Kudos.

Comment: So I added everything after if and it now works...GREAT! Only problem is...what the heck is rf'^{x[2:]}$' and what does it do?

Comment: @Mega r is for string literal and f is for fstring, and the $ is regex that asserts position at the end of a line. You could do test_df['Asset'].str.contains(rf'^{x[2:]}', regex=False) and it would still work

Comment: @MegaDutcher added an explanation for the r- and f-strings

Comment: Thanks guys, this will help me out a bunch...medals all around!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this? If the end has 'USD' but contains more then give it an underscore before USD?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Asset'], data=['1INCH','AAVE','ADA','ALGO','EGLD','DASH','LDO','TUSD','USDT','LD1INCH','LDALGO','LDEGLD','LDDASH','LDLDO','LDTUSD','LDUSDT',])
df['Asset'].apply(lambda x: x[:2]+'_'+x[2:] if len(x) > 2 and x[2:] in df['Asset'].values else x)
```

Comment: No...when x is the 'LDUSD' entry I need it to look through the entire column for 'USD', only if it finds an exact match can the underscore be added. I edited the post with some examples.

Comment: @Mega Oh, I see your update, you need to add an underscore to things starting with LD?

Comment: @Mega I think I finally pieced it together, you want to scan all of assets, to see what congruencies there are between any potential asset with any other asset without the first two characters?

Comment: Yes...but ONLY if it can find a unique copy of x[2:-1], otherwise the code breaks for entries where LD is part of the name e.g. ['EGOLD','LDO'].

Comment: Let's say x is currently 'LDLDO' I want to scan the entire column for an exact match of 'LDO', then add '_' e.g.'LD_LDO'.

Comment: Let's say x is currently 'LDO' it would then be looking for 'O' and fail in which case x remains untouched.